# TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined for formArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using the following code to add form element array to the angular form

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: ['', Validators.required],
    description:[''],
    items: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.control('')
    ])
});
```

Now in the HTML , I have this :

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items.controls?.value; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <td>
        <p>
            <input class="form-control app-login_input-style" 
            type="text" [formControlName]="i">
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>Description of the item</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But this is showing me an error in console like

**DashboardComponent.html:280 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined**

All i need is the following kind of HTML

```
<input type="text" name="items[]">
```

How can I do this ?